# Plugin is not creating object. Showing object state undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating plugin and assigning defaults map to my object. But when i call my plugin, then i get object undefined.
 Here is my code

```
;(function($){

    $.dialog = {

        defaults : {

            timeout: 0 ,
            showClose: true,
            message: "Your message",
            ....

        } //end of defaults

    }; //end of  $.dialog = {}

    $.extend({

        dialog : function(userConfig) {

            var config = (userConfig) ? $.extend({}, $.dialog.defaults, userConfig) 
                                      : $.dialog.defaults;
           $.dialog.createUI(config);

           return this;

       } //end of function(userConfig)

    }); //end of $.fn.extend({})

    $.dialog.createUI = function(config){
        .....
    }

})(jQuery); //end of (function($){}
```

and i am calling it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.dialog();

}); //end of $(document).ready(fn)
```

But i am getting my config object undefined. I cannot access my defaults properties. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your script like this and it worked

```
;(function($){
    $.extend({
        dialog : function(userConfig) {
            var config = (userConfig) ? $.extend({}, $.dialog.defaults, userConfig) : $.dialog.defaults;
            $.dialog.createUI(config);
            return this;
        } //end of function(userConfig)
    }); //end of $.fn.extend({})

    $.dialog.defaults = {
        timeout: 0,
        showClose: true,
        message: "Your message"
    };

    $.dialog.createUI = function(config){

    }
})(jQuery); //end of (function($){}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.dialog();
}); //end of $(document).ready(fn)
```

Comment: @charlietfl No, your suggestion didn't work.Thanks. But what is wrong with my script. What was i did wrong?

Comment: i used `$.dialog.defaults` instead of `$.dialog = { defaults : {`. Is it worked for you?

Comment: yes, that's why i marked your answer:). But `$.dialog.defaults={}` is same as `$.dialog = { defaults : {` . In my case i am first creating an object and then assign property. In your case you are creating and assigning the property on the same line. In both cases **$.dialog** has a proeprty defaults. So what is the difference?

Comment: There is no variable named $.dialog, trying set to value of it doesnt work. But if you change your code `var dialog = { defaults : {` and you can set and get values like `dialog.defaults`

Comment: Thanks.. You mean to say i should used something like `var $.dialog = { defaults : {`, instead of just `$.dialog = { defaults : {`. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.extend({   dialog
```

`dialog` is undefined,  should be `$.dialog`. 
Use console.log to check variables and objects in your code, will save you a lot of time